# Union in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to solve a simple query on mongo

I have two collections `people` and `orders` on two different collections. On sql it those were tables I could do something like this:

```
(SELECT firstname as 'Col1' 
FROM people)

UNION

(SELECT name as 'Col1' 
FROM orders)

OFFSET 20
LIMIT 10;
```

But how can I do it on mongodb? I saw some solutions with aggregate, but that solutions have some field in common when you join them, this collections are totally different, I only want to do a limit and offset on top of the union.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Query**

```
  db.people.aggregate(
  [
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $project: { _id: '$$REMOVE' } },
    { 
         $lookup: { from: 'people', pipeline: [{$project:{Col1:'$firstname'}}], as: 'people' }       
    },
    { 
         $lookup: { from: 'orders', pipeline: [{$project:{Col1:'$name'}}], as: 'orders' } 

    },
    { $project: { union: { $concatArrays: ["$people", "$orders"] } } },
    { $unwind: '$union' },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$union' } },
    {$skip: 20},
    {$limit: 10},
  ]);
```

Comment: See [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds - BSON Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents). Please do not suggest code which proposes to place the entire content of collections inside an array in a single document. The only cases where this is possible is where the entire collection can fit inside 16MB. If that is the case, then you did not need a database in the first place. This simply cannot work at any real practical scale.